# Why can't motors be as elegant as human muscles? Why do we have to use electromagnetism to create movement?

Tags: motor, design

Pretty much as the title says. Why isn't it possible to build motors as microscopically and simply as they're built in humans? Why can't we recreate electronic nerves and muscles?

Comment: `Why isn't it possible`, `Why can't we` ....  why are you making the assumption that it is not possible?  .......... `Why do we have to use electromagnetism to create movement?` what about hydraulically operated heavy equipment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Human muscles take 9 months to grow and maybe 18 months to train for useful motions. It then takes years to refine precision and strength ... and still it falls short of an electric actuator arm in terms if holding power and precision ... but they last 80 years.

Robotic arms are optimized for ease of production, reliability, and strength.  Biological arms are optimized for energy efficiency, among other things like being manufacuted from cells.

"elegance" is hard to define, but I think a Kuka beats a human arm in terms of simplicity, strength, and precision any day.